# Bertrand competition - pure strategy Nash equilibrium

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, self-learning, game-theory

Ihave the following question

[image]

For part (a) my solution is

Since the question says that the two firms compete by simulatanously offering price, this is Bertrand competition

Then the profit function of firm (i) is as follows for all i=1,2

[image]

From the definition of Nash equilibrium

$$p*^*=(200,200) $$ if $$\pi_i(200,200)\ge \pi (p_i,200)$$ for all i

Case 1:

$P^*=(200,200)$ then $\pi^*=0$

Case 2 :

$p^*(p,200)$ where $p<200$ then $0\ge (p-200)(1000-p)$

Case 3 :

$p^*(p,200)$ where $p>200$ then $0\ge (p-200)(1000-p)=0$

So this is Nash equilibrium for $p^*=MC=200$.

I hope so far my solution is true?

My real question is how can I proceed the part b? I am stuck at this point.

All helps are appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: the bound of 300 is important.

Comment: I'm not seeing how the bound of 300 is important. As long as the demand $q(p)$ is positive and $p_2>200$, player 1 can set $p_1$ a tiny bit lower than $p_2$ to take all the demand.

Comment: How is it important? Please help me to solve it. @ericf

Comment: Does it seem Bertrand discrete competition? @ericf

Comment: Is your last sentence correct, can they always take all the demand?

Comment: No they only take maximum 300 demand thus, price can be minimum 700. So price cannot be equal to marginal cast which is 200 @ericf

Comment: @palmpo please hele me to do this question. I am very stack at this question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mnm123 I can't help you, I'm not sure what it means to characterize a pure-strategy NE.